# Rails RSpec testing a simple link redirect_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, response.redirect

I am having difficulty writing an RSpec test in a rails app to make sure that a simple link from my app's homepage redirects to the about page. I have the following in my feature test file:

```
scenario "Have links redirect to the correct paths" do

  visit '/'

  click_link('about')
  expect(response).to redirect_to('about_index_path')

end
```

The link has the id: 'about' and testing from the browser works, but I want to get better with test-driven development. Any suggestions? I've tried multiple variations of the expected result, but I keep getting something like

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `response'
```

or

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `assert_redirect_to'
```

and when I put this in the controller spec I get something like

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `click_link'
```

I can provide more information if necessary, but I think this should be a very simple solution (like testing that the link redirects to 'http://www.google.com') that I'm just not finding. Any other suggested approaches are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response` is not available in feature specs. If you want to assert that the user is on a specific page after clicking a link, try:

```
expect(current_path).to eq about_index_path
```

A feature spec is used to test some functionality through an external interface, such as the browser. In feature specs, you'll generally be asserting against the `page` object.

`click_link` is a Capybara method used to simulate a browser interaction in a feature spec, not a controller spec. A controller spec is used to simulate a single http request, which can assert against the `response` object. A controller spec would be ideal for testing a redirect, especially to an external site:

```
describe "#index" do
  it "redirects to the google homepage"
    get :index

    expect(response).to redirect_to("http://www.google.com")
  end
end
```

If you want to become better at testing, I would suggest learning the different types of tests, when they should be used, and how to write them. There are a ton of great resources out there to help you. Here's a great article that explains a good approach to testing Rails applications:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications